# SwiftUI sync/mask trim of two circles with overlay

Tags: swift, xcode, geometry, swiftui, gradient

I'm sure that there is a very easy solution to this, but I wasn't able to solve it. I overlayed a Circle with another Circle which is filled with a LinearGradient. I want to rotate the circle with LinearGradient (dynamically) without rotating the main circle.

That's because I am using "trim" on my main circle and I want that the trimming starts on the top, that's why I rotated the primary circle 270 degrees.

Currently, I can't see the trimmed first circle of course because it is overlayed with the second circle. Is there a way to mask the second circle so it gets synced with the trimmed, primary circle?

Edit: I added a .mask but I don't like the code since it is redundant. Putting in it a struct would help. Is this the way it's supposed to be done or is there a simpler way?

Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myRotation: Double = 90
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(0.5))
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30))
            .overlay(
                
                Circle()
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30))
                    .fill(LinearGradient(
                        gradient: .init(colors: [Color.red, Color.orange]),
                        startPoint: .top,
                        endPoint: .bottom
                    ))
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.myRotation))
                    .mask(Circle()
                        .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(0.5))
                        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30)))
            )
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270))
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: As it is stated `rotationEffect` is applicable for `View` and `LinearGradient` is *not* a `View`. You can't ask fish to climb a tree. Use to circle - where it works, and combine into another circle or ZStack, if you need something else with it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! However, if I overlay my circle with another one, I can't use "trim" for the first circle because the second circle will cover the whole first one. I also want that "trim" starts on the top, that's why I turned the circle in my code 270 degrees. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: That is different problem - how to achieve what you're going to achieve and it is solvable. Just re-formulate a question according to goal, or put into another topic.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question accordingly. Hope you have an idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the same with removed redundancy (while I'm not sure I got your final goal).

Tested with Xcode 12b

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myRotation: Double = 90
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30))
            .fill(LinearGradient(
                gradient: .init(colors: [Color.red, Color.orange]),
                startPoint: .top,
                endPoint: .bottom
            ))
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.myRotation))
            .mask(Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(0.5))
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30)))
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270))
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one Problem left: The mask circle will move as well if the main circle rotates. I was able to balance that out with applying the inverse of the rotation of the main circle to the mask circle, however, I wondered if there is another way to lock the rotation of the mask circle.

Comment: Edit: I see, order is important. The mask has to come after the rotationEffect. Now it works. Thanks!